# Another way to Call DB2 stored procedure on data integration platform with outputs parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I want to call a DB2 stored procedure on one of the data integration platform, so-called as [Lobster_data](https://www.lobster-world.com/en/products/lobster-data/).

Here, it is one of the example of executing stored procedure.

```
create or replace procedure SP_NAME(
    IN  EXTYP           INT,
    OUT exReturn        VARCHAR(50)
    )

SPECIFIC SP_NAME
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    SET exReturn = 'Your output value';
END

## For calling this DB2 stored procedure, I can use these ways on Data Studio or DBeaver.
(1) "?" for output parameter.
    CALL SP_NAME(123, ?);

(2) Creating variable for output values
    create or replace variable var_output VARCHAR(50);
    CALL SP_NAME(123, var_output);
```

I would like to call the same stored procedure on the data integration platform.
On this platform, (1) is not working and(2), which I don't want.

Are there any other methods for calling stored procedures on DB2?

Comment: This isn't a Db2 Question, this is a Lobster Data question..

Comment: @Charles Thanks for your comment. I am implementing the DB2 code on Lobster_Data. I am wondering, is there another ways to call stored procedure in DB2?

Comment: Can this tool call a compound statement like `BEGIN DECLARE var_output VARCHAR(50); CALL SP_NAME(123, var_output); END`?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thanks for your comment. Actually not. But this compound statement will also save output to the DB2. The main problem is that, if same compound statement run for multiple at same time, it is hard to define which outputs belongs to which one.

Comment: I don't understand meaning of "save output to Db2". Actually, I've provided the way to call a routine with an inout/out parameter, when an application-caller can't work with these types of routine parameters. Seems, you want something impossible - to make a tool which can't work with these types of parameters to display their value. How would you want to get the output parameter value? With some distinct CALL / SELECT statement? After a single routine call or after multiple calls?

Comment: Let us suppose, at the same time, the same call run on the different jobs on this tool. All var_output variable will save under the global variables (var_output) on the same schema. And after that, if we would like to use the variable for different routine job, then it is difficult to say which job's variables are we taking.

Comment: consider `var_output` use in my command as `/dev/null`. It's a local variable inside the compound statement with the only purpose: to "eat" the routine output allowing you just to call this routine without an error. If you really need the output value, then yes, it's more convenient to use a global variable presuming that you make multiple related calls with the same connection.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Hey Mark, thanks for your answer, can you please more elaborate about /dev/null ?